# Can I replace an old commit with a commit from another branch?

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

Suppose I have a branch B1 whose last commits are C1 -> C2 -> C3 , and another branch B2 whose last commits are C4 -> C5 -> C6.

How can I replace commit C2 on B1 with, say, commit C4 from B2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with an interactive rebase - but *not* a rebase of B1 on B2. Rather, do:

```
git rebase -i B1 hash-of-C2^
```

<sub>(instead of hash-of-C2 you'll type in the actual hash of C2, i.e. the hexadecimal string which looks like `ddc18e47147f4f5cb969609150c4d29040b2c07f` which you can see using `git log`)</sub>

then, in the editor, you'll see:

```
pick short-hash-of-C2 commit comment here
pick short-hash-of-C3 commit comment here
```

<sub>(the short-hash will be a prefix of the full hash of C2, e.g. `ddc18e47`)</sub>

Now, replace the `keep` with `drop` for C2, but add a line for C4, so that you now have:

```
drop short-hash-of-C2 commit comment here
pick full-hash-of-C4
pick short-hash-of-C3 commit comment here
```

<sub>(Note that the short hash of C4 should also work, but I like to just copy the whole hash and not shorten it in case I mess it up.)</sub>

That's it. Of course you may need to resolve conflicts due to these changes, just as in any rebase.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these branches are both published, you might want to go with a revert/cherry-pick option:

```
# on branch B1
git revert C2
git cherry-pick C4
```

This would leave branch `B1` looking like the following:

```
C1 -- C2 -- C3 -- RC2 -- C4
```

But functionally it should roughly the same as:

```
C1 -- C4 -- C3
```

Comment: So, +1 for the alternative, but I would rather not have these "scars" in the commit log. Also - can you elaborate  on what you mean by the branches being "published"?

Comment: @einpoklum Your answer is rewriting history, and one usually does not have this liberty should a branch already be published and shared with multiple people.

Comment: Tim Biegelesien: So you mean "published" in the literal sense, of being accessible and possible used by many people?

Comment: Yes, because in that case, if you rewrite history you will cause problems for anyone else who has that branch checked out locally.